# Resetting view to default tab with react-web-tabs

Tags: reactjs

My default tab is Income. I have a dropdown component on top of Tab. If the value in dropdown changes i need to reset the view to default tab(income). Please help me on this.

```
           <Tabs
              defaultTab="income"
              onChange={(tabId) => { console.log(tabId) }}>
              <TabList>
                <Tab tabFor="income">Income</Tab>
                <Tab tabFor="expense">Expense</Tab>
                <Tab tabFor="liability">Liabilities</Tab>
              </TabList>
              <TabPanel tabId="income">
               <p>Income</p>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel tabId="expense">
                <p>Expense</p>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel tabId="liability">
                <p>Liability</p>
              </TabPanel>
            </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your defaultTab value as a state so it will be dynamic either and update accordingly when needed(in your case onChange value of your dropdown component.

e.g.

```
 class TabSample extends React.Component {

    state = {
      defaultTab: 'Income'
    }

    onDropdownChange = () => {
     // reset default tab value to initial state
     this.setState({defaultTab: 'Income'})
    }

    render(){
     const { defaultTab } = this.state;
     return <Tabs
              defaultTab={defaultTab}
              onChange={(tabId) => { console.log(tabId) }}>
              <TabList>
                <Tab tabFor="income">Income</Tab>
                <Tab tabFor="expense">Expense</Tab>
                <Tab tabFor="liability">Liabilities</Tab>
              </TabList>
              <TabPanel tabId="income">
               <p>Income</p>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel tabId="expense">
                <p>Expense</p>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel tabId="liability">
                <p>Liability</p>
              </TabPanel>
            </Tabs>
     }

    }
```